# Laravel 4.2 Sort by Eloquent Relationship Problems

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-4.2

I'm working with a datatable that I'm outputting from various relationships.

Most of the data comes from a `meters` table that has a `Meter` model, but some of it is pulled from other tables via relationships. For instance, I'm having an issue with sorting by the `calibrations` table.

The datatable has sortable columns that work just fine. The columns that sort based on other relationships have the joins in place so that they sort without any query errors.

All the sorting and joins work except for one, `last_calibration_date`.

There is no column called `last_calibration_date`. In fact, each `meter` could have multiple calibrations.

In the `Meter` model I grab the `last_calibration_date` from the `calibrations` table via the `calibration_date` column this way:

```
public function getLastCalibrationDateAttribute()
{
    if (isset($this->relations['calibrations']) && $this->relations['calibrations']->count())
        return $this->relations['calibrations']->sortBy('calibration_date', SORT_REGULAR, true)->first()->calibration_date->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

This works superbly when I'm not sorting by the `last_calibration_date` column, but returns a sql error if you try to sort by it without a join.

Here's my attempt at the join:

```
if ($sort == 'last_calibration_date')
{
    $query->join('calibrations', 'calibrations.meter_id', '=', 'meters.id');
    $sort = 'calibrations.calibration_date';
}
```

While this doesn't return an error it also doesn't return the actual `last_calibration_date`.

Just a little more info, the `calibrations` table is set up like so

```
calibrations
- id
- calibration_date
- next_calibration_date
- meter_id
```

So, as was said previously, any meter may have multiple calibrations.

Any ideas on how I could replicate my `Meter` method in my join? Or maybe another way of sorting by `last_calibration_date`?

Comment: Upgrade to 5.2 , you are in past!

Comment: Still would have the same issues.

Comment: TBH using DB::raw for this will be less headache for you.

Comment: @guyfawkes you are probably right about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alrighty, well, I seem to have solved my problem without quite understanding why.

```
if ($sort == 'last_calibration_date')
{
     $query->select('meters.*');
     $query->join('calibrations as calibration', 'calibration.meter_id', '=', 'meters.id');
     $sort = 'calibration.calibration_date';
}
```

Adding that `$query->select('meters.*');` has solved it. Again, not sure why. My understanding is that is selecting a particular table's columns, not a model's relationships.

Anyways, it's working now.